# data-remote true defining a callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, rest

I have a form that I would like to submit with the `data-remote=true` option.  But I want to have my create action return json, then have that handled by javascript that already exists on the page.  Can I set a callback inline with the form_for tag?

Something similar to this:

```
=form_for @foo,:remote => true, :success => "my_js_stuff" do |f|
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will be possible without overriding rails form helper. But you can use jquery ajax events and bind to them. For example:

```
$('form#sign-up-form').ajaxError(function(event, request, settings) {
 //do some stuff on error
})

$('form#sign-up-form').bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr){
//do some stuff on success
})
```

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to define a create.js.erb and/or update.js.erb for the foo controller. That will return javascript that you'll execute.

From there, you can execute javascript that already exists on the page.

Comment: Good thinking. +1 This will help in case of a success. Will not help in case of an error.