# How do I create and get an active record using ajax in Rails 3?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In Rails 3.2 I'm trying to figure out how to use ajax to create an ActiveRecord model instance. Basically I want to take form fields, send them to the server with ajax, and get the model instance back. Surprisingly, I can't find a single example of this on stackoverflow or elsewhere.

Does anyone have an example of this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an action in your controller, responding for both formats (html and json):

```
# app/controllers/bananas_controller.rb
class BananasController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @banana = Banana.new(params[:banana])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @banana.save
        format.html { redirect_to @banana, notice: 'Banana was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @banana, status: :created, location: @banana }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @banana.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You'll also need to add the route:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :bananas, :only => [:create]
```

For a complete example, use the scaffold command (maybe on another application) to create the model, views and controller:

```
rails generate scaffold banana
```

Comment: Thanks Alfonso. I should have been more explicit in my question. The part confusing me is the actual javascript for the call and receive methods. (My ruby and rails is far stronger than my javascript.)

Comment: @hershey From what I understand, you don't need to use javascript at all, just create the `form_for` with `:remote => true`

Comment: Thanks Alfonso. Although that will only work in the case where I'm using form for. (If I'm using a form not tied to a specific model then I need to do the explicit invokation by ajax.  I think I can just do it with an xmlhttp.open GET request.)  With `:remote => true` how do I catch the response?  My goal is to create a new active record instance but having the user stay on the same page--as opposed to the user's browser opening a new page.

Comment: You can still use `:remote => true` with a custom form as long as you use the rails `form_tag` helper. Inside that form, you add the fields that you want (either hidden or not). You can submit that form programmatically using `.submit()`. For the callback, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955216/data-remote-true-defining-a-callback . The advantage of using rails forms is that you won't break [CSRF security](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf)

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help! I was able to get it to work.