# turbolinks:load event not firing on remote true call, rails, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks-5

I have a simple js file in `app/assets/javascripts/media_preview_script.js`

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $("#cat").on('click', function() {
    showBrowseInput()
  })
})
function showBrowseInput () {
  do stuff here
}
```

Supposedly `turbolinks:load` makes this script attach on first page load and then any turbolinks call after that, but it will not do so. It only loads when the page loads then any `remote: true` call that comes back events are not attached. This is the same with any script I have in my app.

This is happening because of the `$(document).on('turbolinks:load'...` at the beginning, when I remove this and if I include the file in the view form with `<%= javascript_include_tag "file_name" %>` I do not get double attachment on document and the events will attach every js call or page load. So my question is, does javascript_include_tag add in a turbolinks function? Or can anyone tel me what is going on here. I am using rails 5.

layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

javascipt include tag api doc [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag) and layouts and rendering [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `remote: true` makes it all work with ajax. You can handle the events you want with this code:

```
$('form').ajaxError(function(event, request, settings) {
  // your code
})

$('form').bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr){
  // your code
})
```

as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8956770/2162591

UPDATE:

The only problem I got with this solution is that ajax:success is triggered before the page fully refreshed. I used this code instead:

```
$('form').bind('turbolinks:request-end', function(evt, data, status, xhr){
    // your code
});
```

Comment: really I was getting confused with turbolinks and remote :true. Thankyou!